# Marx generator for quick discharge of capacitors on inductor

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, capacitance, capacitor-charging

[image: Schematic]

My goal was to charge these two capacitors with a DC generator as shown in the schematic using a Cockcroft-Walton generator.  This has worked in the lab perfectly.

The capacitors are charged in parallel.  My goal was to switch them somehow in series and drive an RLC oscillation.

My idea was to use a modified Marx generator with the switch S1 open during the charging phase. When S1 closes, the capacitors would be in series (60 volts) driving the oscillation. R1 and R2 are both 1 MΩ and R3 is 10Ω.

I am having a hard time figuring out why I am not getting the expected outcome.

When closing S1 I am expecting the capacitors to discharge, but measuring the voltage at their leads does not show that as I am getting 30V continuously.

The capacitors are polypropylene 150nF rated at 630 VDC 400VAC.

Comment: C1 charges (quite quickly), but C2 is mostly shorted by L1,R3. You seem to think it will charge to 30V?

Comment: Well i have built the circuit in the lab and having the S1 open I have measured 30V on each capacitor.

Comment: I really doubt your measurement was correct for C2 or the schematic isn't the same.

Comment: C1 serves no purpose on an ideal voltage source.  A Marx generator uses DC cascaded with high impedance charging R then an ignition spark to switch on all the gaps to close and put the caps in series.  Then you must consider the inductor is not arc gap isolated so it will always dicharge the output.

Comment: What do you mean it serves no purpose. My problem even in Lt Spice is that when i only have the resistor R3 (lets say 10Ω)  and i close S1 the peak current on the resxistance is 30 amps supposing the caps where charged at 150V each. In reality i have measured them and they are charged at 150 V each. My problem is that even on LT Spice adding an inductor L1 with 2Ω series resistance drops the peak current  to mA...which I cannot explain.

Comment: "tesla-coil" should not have been a tag. This has absolutely nothing to do with Tesla coils

Comment: Yes but these kinds of circuits are usually used in tesla guns. So i thought someone would help me out. Thanks for the help brother!

Comment: @KostisPapadakis "Tesla guns" are entirely different, they are actually based around Tesla coils. The style is called a Quasi-Continuous-Wave Dual Resonant Solid State Tesla Coil, or "QCWDRSSTC" for short. Marx generators are not used in any Tesla guns unless the creator of the gun has no clue what a Tesla coil actually is and mis-named it.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know, but maybe the resistor is disturbing the oscillation.  I know you don't lose current through them, but they dampen the spring. I am pretty sure you should try without it.  I bet you did though and nothing worked.

LC oscillations only last very temporarily.  You need a huge inductor,  but I haven't actually done it much before.

I think you are best off to actually put a capacitor with a diode, and see if the capacitor charges.  You have to use 100 microfarads at least or you won't be able to register anything on your voltmeter.

Even that might not work, I'd have to come round your house and do it with you and unfortunately may come up with bugger all brcause I haven't got mine working yet either.

I think a capacitor and a diode might register a small voltage increase, but the diode will lose some volts, and other crud might happen,  but I think you should lose the 1ohms.

You are definitely on the right track, you'll get it eventually.

Comment: I found your answer quite confusing. Although @VoltageSpike edited it, it is still not clear. Suggestion: use *citation* button or “>” to refer to the part you intend to answer or explain. And that “come around your house…” doesn’t add at all; consider repharsing/deleting it when you revise your true replies & meanings.